# How to mock returned value from a react hook in Jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs

I have a custom hook `useAuth0`. I need to mock a specific function (`logout`) returned by the hook and keep the real funcionality of the rest. Is there a solution for this case?

I tried:

```js
jest.spyOn(useAuth0(), 'logout') // invalid hook call
```

```js
jest.mock('lib/hooks/useAuth0', () => () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('lib/hooks/useAuth0'),
  logout: jest.fn()
})) // mocking the module instead of the returned value

expect(useAuth0().logout).toHaveBeenCalled() // fails - logout not called
```

Comment: Just FYI, `useAuth0()` immediately invokes the hook, outside a React component, which breaks the Rules of Hooks. Try making the spy first so you've a reference to it, mock the hook, then assert the spy was called.

Comment: You may also want to consider [react-hooks-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/) for testing your custom React hooks in isolation.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your help. What do you mean by calling spy first to have a reference?

Comment: You are directly mocking the `logout` function but keep no reference to it. I mean to create a mock function first, i.e. `const logoutMock = jest.fn();` and pass this to the hook you are mocking, i.e. `logout: logoutMock,`, then assert the mock function was called, e.g. `expect(logoutMock).toHaveBeenCalled();`. Does this make sense?